# How to calculate the limit in this question?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

There is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n+ \frac{1}{a_1+a_2+ \cdots +a_n}$. Then find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2 \ln n}}$

Comment: Interesting question. Where does it come from?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you worked out $a_n,$ at least for small values of $n$?

Comment: The question comes from a part of Chinese homework of mathematical analysis.

Comment: Assuming that the limit exists, it can be computed in a simple way from Cesàro theorems. So the problem is reduced to showing that the wanted limit exists. Anyway, you should include some attempt.